# Asymmetric Bar Placement in Overhead Position

Tags: strength, upper-body-workout, mobility, overheadpress, overhead-squat

Hell there,
I have an issue in any kind of exercises involving the Overhead Position (Overhead Press e Overhead Squat).

Precisely, at the Overhead lockout position (shoulder blades elevated and [arms slightly internally rotated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCaBBDXKbj4)) I cannot keep the barbell in the frontal plane, but rather it rotates so that it is in front of the mid-foot on the right side and behind the mid-foot on the left. I tried to let it be visualized in the following picture:

[image]

This implies that:

- in the lockout position of the Overhead Press, **my torso is slightly twisted** (although I still can get a stable lockout in this exercise).
- in the Overhead Squat, during both the way up and down, t**he weight shifts continuously from my heel to my toes and viceversa**, because I can't get balanced during the movement. I think this is caused by the barbell rotation described above.

So, I wanted to ask you if you have some tips to fix it. I've noticed that, if I perform both exercises with the Kettlebells, this problem disappears and I'm quite symmetric. But when I get the barbell, it causes a rotation of my torso and it stays as depicted above. Moreover, I've noticed that such a rotation increases with the load. But also with a 15kg barbell it exists.

I do not know which muscle unbalance causes it, so I wanted to know if there is a general shoulders-arms mobility routine to help fix this.

Comment: Stability/balance shouldn’t be affected by an off-axis bar if the bar is static. Shoulder mobility (and anything related to being able to keep the arm back) stretches/exercises will help with the right side being too far forward, although it’s not clear which side is potentially out of position (e.g., the right side could be too far forward or the left side could be too far back—or both). Are you sure the KB lift is symmetrical? Or does it just *feel* like it is?

Comment: @DaveNewton From an external point of view, the KB lift looks like symmetrical, and also I feel more balanced. About which side is out of position it seems both: the right side too far forward and the left side too far back. Do you know some cues to help understand if the bar is too far forward/or back?

Comment: I'd take a picture or a video, or just look to the left/right. The balance thing confuses me. Keep in mind that KBs, assuming un-inverted, are going to have a different center of gravity because their weight is mostly behind the hand, sort of "pulling" your arms back. I suppose you could check relative hand positioning with the barbell and make sure they're symmetrical; if (say) one hand was bent back more it'd (slightly) change the weight distribution.

Comment: Maybe you can test the range of shoulder flexion for both sides. Do it unilaterally. Sounds like your right shoulder lacks full ROM during flexion. If you can’t get full or the same amount of shoulder flexion for both arms, the barbell will be twisted. If you lack the range for your right shoulder. you can try foam rolling your pecs and lats to see if it helps. Also, train your shoulder external rotators